# when hover on image or text the both scale

Tags: html, css

i want when the user hover on the image or the text and the image scale.i have tried this but only one scale

```css
.top3 , .top1 {
transition: all 1s ease; 
}
.top3:hover ,.top1:hover {
transform: scale(1.17);
}
```

```html
<div class="top3" id="DSC0123"><a href=""><img src="images/DSC0123.png"></a></div>
<div class="top3" id="Layer4"><a href=""><img src="images/Layer4.png"></a></div>
<div class="top3" id="DSC0416"><a href=""><img src="images/DSC0416.png"></a></div>
<div class="top3" id="IMG0541"><a href=""><img src="images/IMG0541.png"></a></div>
<div class="top3 top3" id="DSC0331"><a href=""><img src="images/DSC03311.png"></a></div>
<div class="top1 top3" id="Food"><a href="">Food</a></div>
<div class="top1 top3" id="portrait"><a href="">Food</a></div>
<div class="top1 top3" id="LANSCAPES"><a href="">Food</a></div>
<div class="top1 top3" id="kids"><a href="">Food</a></div>
<div class="top1 top3" id="SPORTS"><a href="">Food</a></div>
```

Comment: Can you please add a jsFiddle?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The user wants BOTH to scale (the img and the text)

You should put the text div inside the image div, like this:

```
 <div class="top3" id="DSC0123">
   <a href=""><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" /></a>
   <div class="top1 top3" id="Food">
    <a href="">Food</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/933ex7pv/2/ (working fiddle)

Add `transform-origin: 0 0;` (or some other values that you like) to make it scale in the center.

Comment: Downvoted for giving the right answer? That's useful.

Comment: sorry i didn't see it works but the element place changed  and its moved from the image is there is a solution or just replace it manually

Comment: The fiddle is working, the text is moving outside of the frame because the scaling method is not centered, it is scaling tho.

Comment: yes i know its scaling is there is a way to center it ?

Comment: @SayedHasan you can check the answer again, you just needed to add the transform-origin css property. Try a few times to see the best result for you.

Comment: @SayedHasan if all you want is the text to scale and be in the middle, just add a text-align center to your CSS rules

Comment: @SayedHasan check out this new fiddle, it should do what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/933ex7pv/2/

Did it work and answer your question?

Comment: if i want it on the image and middle i use absolute?

Comment: No, you just need both the image and the text to be display: inline-block so you can use block element qualities but still be inline.

You can then put text-align: center and if not yet centered, give it a width and make the margin: 0 auto; 

With this you can center almost anything. Worst case scenario you have to put the parent positioning to relative and the child positioning to absolute with top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;


text-align: center should be enough if your HTML is exactly like in my js fiddle

Comment: @SayedHasan answer is up one comment. If it works would you please choose my answer so I regain the points that some nuthead chose to make lose for no reason? Thanks.

Comment: Use jsfiddle and copy your code over there, then send me the link!

Comment: @SayedHasan those images are on your computer so I can't see them from here. You need to put some images that are uploaded on the internet or upload your own and modify the images' links.

Answer (score 2):

Use `display` on `<a>` and apply hover on `<a>`, like:

```
.top3 , .top1 {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.top3 a, .top1 a {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.top3:hover a ,.top1:hover a {
  transform: scale(1.17);
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.top3 , .top1 {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.top3 a, .top1 a {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.top3 a:hover ,.top1 a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="top3" id="DSC0123"><a href=""><img src="images/DSC0123.png"></a></div>
<div class="top3" id="Layer4"><a href=""><img src="images/Layer4.png"></a></div>
<div class="top3" id="DSC0416"><a href=""><img src="images/DSC0416.png"></a></div>
<div class="top3" id="IMG0541"><a href=""><img src="images/IMG0541.png"></a></div>
<div class="top3 top3" id="DSC0331"><a href=""><img src="images/DSC03311.png"></a></div>
<div class="top1 top3" id="Food"><a href="">Food</a></div>
<div class="top1 top3" id="portrait"><a href="">Food</a></div>
<div class="top1 top3" id="LANSCAPES"><a href="">Food</a></div>
<div class="top1 top3" id="kids"><a href="">Food</a></div>
<div class="top1 top3" id="SPORTS"><a href="">Food</a></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: still the same when i hover the <a> it the only element that scaled also the the image when i hover it it the only scale

Comment: @SayedHasan So, you want that if the user hover the `<a>` it should only scale and if you hover over `<img>` then image should only scale? Currently if you hover on a div the <a> or <img> tag only scales.

Comment: i want when i hover the image or when i hover the <a> both img and <a> scales at the same time.

Comment: srry bro still the same

Comment: @SayedHasan Then I can't really understand what you really want?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want an image to scale up/down on hover, but not the text. You can do this without duplicating links and with fewer, more robust code. I've made an example to demonstrate, and added borders for ease. You can do whatever you like on hover, of course. I kept it simple.

```
a {
display: block;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;

border: solid 1px red;
}

a img {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
}

a span {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;

border: solid 1px green;
}

a:hover {
width: 600px;
height: 600px;
}

a:hover span {
width 600px;
}

a:hover img {
width: 600px;
height: 500px;
}


<a href="#"><img src="http://img05.deviantart.net/c135/i/2011/134/7/0/bridge_by_kzonedd-d3gcetc.jpg" alt="old wooden bridge" /><span>text</span></a>
```